# Como arredondar float em C sem usar printf()

Tags: c, float, arredondamento

Não estou conseguindo arredondar o *float* para as duas primeiras casas decimais.

Escrevi meu programa assim:

```
float valor;

scanf("%f", &valor);
printf("valor = %f\n", valor);
```

Depois de compilado, digitei **573.93** para testar, e o que retornou foi:

```
valor = 573.929993
```

Tentei usar a função *round()* da biblioteca *math.h*,mas também não funcionou. Usei assim:

```
float valor;

scanf("%f", &valor);

printf("1° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
valor = round(valor*100.0)/100.0;
printf("2° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
```

E retornou isso:

```
1° valor = 573.929993
2° valor = 573.929993
```

Também usei assim:

```
float valor;

scanf("%f", &valor);

printf("1° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
valor = valor * 10.0;
printf("2° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
valor = valor * 10.0;
printf("3° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
valor = round(valor);
printf("4° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
valor = valor/100.0;
printf("5° valor = %f\n", valor);//TESTE
```

E o que retornou foi:

```
1° valor = 573.929993
2° valor = 5739.299805
3° valor = 57393.000000
4° valor = 57393.000000
5° valor = 573.929993
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a arredondar o *float* para *valor = 573.93*?

Comment: Veja aí que o que você fez é o que dá para fazer, mas o problema é usar `float` quando se deseja exatidão, ele não fornece isso. Nunca use ponto flutuante binário para dinheiro.

Comment: Se é precisão apenas para impressão, você pedir isso: 

`printf("%.0f\n", valor)`; 

irá imprimir sem nenhuma casa depois do ponto, do mesmo modo que .1 irá imprimir uma casa depois do ponto, assim por diante.